# How to remove header square from chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

How to remove header square from chart js?
Maybe there is a way to hide it or make it white?

I tried `options {legend: {display: false}}` but it's hide only text

Comment: PLease show your code, create a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using V3 of chart.js while using V2 syntax. In v3 you have to configure it in the `options.plugins.legend` namespace.

```js
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
}
```